# Google Earth Engine error message “Error: Input has missing or invalid affine transform”

Tags: google-earth-engine, gdal-translate

Firstly, apologies for repeated question - this question was already asked over at [Google Earth Engine error message “Error: Input has missing or invalid affine transform” [duplicate]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345817/google-earth-engine-error-message-error-input-has-missing-or-invalid-affine-tr) where the only response before it was closed points to this question [Google Earth Engine error invalid affine transform [closed]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345813/google-earth-engine-error-invalid-affine-transform) which now gives a 404 error.

My issue comes from using `gdal_translate` on a subdataset of the NetCDF [ESA CCI Land Cover data](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/satellite-land-cover?tab=form). The call to `gdal_translate` is as follows:

`gdal_translate -of GTiff HDF5:"C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2017-v2.1.1.nc"://lccs_class ESA_CCI_LC_V2-1-1_2017.tif -a_srs EPSG:4326`

This is using GDAL v3.1.2 on a Windows 10 system with Python 3.7.5.

The call works and visual inspection of the output in QGIS seems normal. On upload to GEE, however, I get the "Error: Input has missing or invalid affine transform" on asset ingestion. Am I missing something from the GDAL call or is this something else?

**EDIT:**
As user30184 correctly pointed out the solution specifying the extent with `-a_ullr` can only be correct if that data is contained in the source data which you can run with:

`gdalinfo HDF5:"C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2017-v2.1.1.nc"://lccs_class`

Which gives the following output:

```
Driver: HDF5Image/HDF5 Dataset
Files: C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2018-v2.1.1.nc
Size is 129600, 64800
Metadata:
  cdm_data_type=grid
  comment=
  contact=copernicus-support@ecmwf.int
  Conventions=CF-1.6
  creation_date=20190819T082510Z
  creator_email=landcover-cci@uclouvain.be
  creator_name=UCLouvain
  creator_url=http://www.uclouvain.be/
  geospatial_lat_max=90.0
  geospatial_lat_min=-90.0
  geospatial_lat_resolution=0.002778
  geospatial_lat_units=degrees_north
  geospatial_lon_max=null
  geospatial_lon_min=null
  geospatial_lon_resolution=0.002778
  geospatial_lon_units=degrees_east
  history=lc-sr-1.0, lc-classification-1.0,lc-user-tools-3.14,lc-user-tools-4.3
  id=C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2018-v2.1.1
  institution=UCLouvain
  keywords=land cover classification,satellite,observation
  keywords_vocabulary=NASA Global Change Master Directory (GCMD) Science Keywords
  license=EC C3S Land cover Data Policy
  naming_authority=
  product_version=2.1.1
  project=EC C3S Land cover
  references=https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/
  source=PROBA-V
  spatial_resolution=300m
  standard_name_vocabulary=NetCDF Climate and Forecast (CF) Standard Names version 21
  summary=This dataset characterizes the land cover of a particular year (see time_coverage). The land cover was derived from the analysis of satellite data time series of the full period.
  TileSize=2025:2025
  time_coverage_duration=P1Y
  time_coverage_end=20181231
  time_coverage_resolution=P1Y
  time_coverage_start=20180101
  title=Land Cover Map of 2018
  tracking_id=b0ea3056-933e-408a-9f58-99c2072c3cb2
  type=C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y
  _NCProperties=version=1|netcdflibversion=4.6.0|hdf5libversion=1.10.0
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,64800.0)
Upper Right (129600.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (129600.0,64800.0)
Center      (64800.0,32400.0)
Band 1 Block=2025x2025 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Metadata:
    lccs_class_ancillary_variables=processed_flag current_pixel_state observation_count change_count
    lccs_class_flag_colors=#ffff64 #ffff64 #ffff00 #aaf0f0 #dcf064 #c8c864 #006400 #00a000 #00a000 #aac800 #003c00 #003c00 #005000 #285000 #285000 #286400 #788200 #8ca000 #be9600 #966400 #966400 #966400 #ffb432 #ffdcd2 #ffebaf #ffc864 #ffd278 #ffebaf #00785a #009678 #00dc82 #c31400 #fff5d7 #dcdcdc #fff5d7 #0046c8 #ffffff
    lccs_class_flag_meanings=no_data cropland_rainfed cropland_rainfed_herbaceous_cover cropland_rainfed_tree_or_shrub_cover cropland_irrigated mosaic_cropland mosaic_natural_vegetation tree_broadleaved_evergreen_closed_to_open tree_broadleaved_deciduous_closed_to_open tree_broadleaved_deciduous_closed tree_broadleaved_deciduous_open tree_needleleaved_evergreen_closed_to_open tree_needleleaved_evergreen_closed tree_needleleaved_evergreen_open tree_needleleaved_deciduous_closed_to_open tree_needleleaved_deciduous_closed tree_needleleaved_deciduous_open tree_mixed mosaic_tree_and_shrub mosaic_herbaceous shrubland shrubland_evergreen shrubland_deciduous grassland lichens_and_mosses sparse_vegetation sparse_tree sparse_shrub sparse_herbaceous tree_cover_flooded_fresh_or_brakish_water tree_cover_flooded_saline_water shrub_or_herbaceous_cover_flooded urban bare_areas bare_areas_consolidated bare_areas_unconsolidated water snow_and_ice
    lccs_class_flag_values=0 10 11 12 20 30 40 50 60 61 62 70 71 72 80 81 82 90 100 110 120 121 122 130 140 150 151 152 153 160 170 180 190 200 201 202 210 220
    lccs_class_long_name=Land cover class defined in LCCS
    lccs_class_standard_name=land_cover_lccs
    lccs_class_valid_max=220
    lccs_class_valid_min=1
```

In addition, the [docs](http://datastore.copernicus-climate.eu/documents/satellite-land-cover/D3.3.12-v1.2_PUGS_ICDR_LC_v2.1.x_PRODUCTS_v1.2.pdf) for the data say:

> The C3S LC project delivers the global LC maps at 0.002778° (approximately 300 m) spatial resolution for 2016 to 2018 (version 2.1). The Coordinate Reference System used for the global land cover database is a geographic coordinate system (GCS) based on the World Geodetic System 84(WGS84) reference ellipsoid.

Which implies the same information for crs and extent.

Comment: Please run `gdalinfo HDF5:"C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2017-v2.1.1.nc"://lccs_class` and add the report into your question. Perhaps it contains data that proves your usage of `-a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr -180 90 180 -90` correct.

Comment: Could this error be caused by weak internet conection ? here is my case: Image size: 900Mb -1Gb Phase: Failed
Runtime: 3m (started 2023-06-13 11:09:58 -0300)
Attempted 1 time
Error: Input has missing or invalid affine transform. Source filename: ICEYE_X4_GRD_SM_22783_20200224T185541.tif (Error code: 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this now so here's the answer for anyone else stuck.

At least in my case, this error is due to my output tif not having an extent associated with it. I reran the `gdal_translate` call specifying the extent with `-a_ullr`. In my case that was this call:

`gdal_translate -of GTiff HDF5:"C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2017-v2.1.1.nc"://lccs_class ESA_CCI_LC_V2-1-1_2017.tif -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr -180 90 180 -90`